# MYSQL importing dump completed with errors

Tags: mysql

when I try to import my exported dump file (specifically my database/schema) to other computer, I got this error;

> D:\CAPSTONE SYSTEM\MyDataBaseCAPSTONE\Dump20150922\schm_capstonesystem_routines.sql does not contain schema/table information
>   16:58:55 Restoring schm_capstonesystem (employee_entry)
>   Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\kc\appdata\local\temp\tmpnowdu_.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=schm_capstonesystem < "D:\CAPSTONE SYSTEM\MyDataBaseCAPSTONE\Dump20150922\schm_capstonesystem_employee_entry.sql"
>   ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'schm_capstonesystem'
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

Please help~! :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is `Unknown database`. You have to create the database 'schm_capstonesystem' first.
And then run the import of your dump.

Comment: okay? should I have to create the 'schm_capstonesystem' database first before importing?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know how to create the schema as in the answer above:
right Click the left pane under Schema in SQL, click create schema,enter a name for the schema (preferably the same as the db your importing) click apply. Then do the import